# Using ARRAY function to return numerical value based on new month. When false would like value to come from another column of numbers based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$44:$C$46,MATCH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,$B$44:$B$46,0)),0)
```

True date in B44:B46, return the corresponding value in C44:C46.
False date in B44:B46, return the corresponding value in D44:D46.

When I try to revise the false statement to an Array I get #N/A.

Comment: Some sample date with expected results would be helpful.

Comment: 1.  You should use VLookup(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,$B$44:$B$46,2,false) instead of match & index combination.  2.  It is VERY unclear what you mean by "false date in B44:B46".  If the match fails, there is no corresponding value in D44:D46 and there is nothing to return.

Comment: @Ekalb.  Thanks for raising / welcome.  Assuming you wish to return from C:C if today exists in B:B, and from D:D whenever this not the case... if so, see proposed soln. below...  (PS - suggest asking a Q directly instead of simply making a statement! :)

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98QGQSrCdhmAL3B78?e=xgZiXQ) refer:

[image: Screenshot]

This creates an array comprising C:C whenever corresponding cells in B:B = 1/07 (D:D used instead of C:C otherwise).

The following requires Office 365 version of Excel/equivalent:

=LET(date_VAR, EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,IF(B2:B6=date_VAR,C2:C6,D2:D6))

PS - I considered an index/match equivalent but the issue with this is that it is prone to only returning the 1st valid match (so if you had 2 cells in B:B = 1/07 then only the 1st corresponding value in C:C would be returned; same for whenever B:B didn't contain this date)..